# Maximum Margin of Error

Tags: inference, statistical-power

Here's a stats question I'm having trouble with:

Suppose the researchers plan to do a follow-up study in the future to once again estimate
π = the true proportion of the population that gets help for pain associated with joint pain or stiffness from acupuncture (In the study, 31 of 32 of the respondents reported that they got help from the acupuncture treatment). They want the margin of error to be at most ± 3%. How large of a sample size will they need to ensure that the margin of error would not exceed this amount?

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this problem? Would I just set the margin of error equal to .03 and do: .03 = 1.96 sqrt(.96875(1 - 0.96875))/n) and do solve for n? Am I on the rigth track?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error#Calculations_assuming_random_sampling